# Javascript if not in dictionary (node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, logic, express

Here's the code:

```
exports.index_post = function(req, res) {
  var nicks = [];
  if (req.body.nick) {
    for (var nick in nicks) {
      if (nick == req.body.nick) {
        res.redirect("/");
      } else {
        nicks.push(req.body.nick)
        req.session.nick = req.body.nick;
        res.redirect("/msg");
        console.log(nicks);
      }
    }
  } else {
    res.redirect("/");
  }
};
```

What it's meant to do is check if req.body.nick is one of the items in the nicks dictionary, and if if is redirect it back to the root. If it's not in the dictionary, it should add it to the dictionary and set it as a session variable, then redirect to /msg. However, this code doesn't seem to be working for me and instead it causes Express to hang. Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Arrays are not dictionaries. Also, your logic is completely broken — you are redirecting the request _once for each element in `nicks`_, i.e. if you have 10 elements there, you would try to redirect the request 10 times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you're creating a new `nicks` array every time the function is run; it sounds like you want this to persist throughout the life of the server, each request potentially adding to the `nicks` array. Also, though you're iterating over the array looking for `req.body.nick`, the way the `if/else` statement is written inside the loop, it will *always* redirect on the very first iteration through the loop. Try something like this:

```
var nicks = []; // don't reset `nicks` every call

exports.index_post = function(req, res) {
  if (req.body.nick) {
    if (nicks.indexOf(req.body.nick) != -1) { // better checking for nick in nicks
      res.redirect("/");
    } else {
      nicks.push(req.body.nick)
      req.session.nick = req.body.nick;
      res.redirect("/msg");
      console.log(nicks);
    }
  } else {
    res.redirect("/");
  }
};
```

Comment: Ah... Thanks! I understand how it was working now. And your solution works :) Thanks again! I'll accept your answer ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your `nicks` is empty

   so your for loop won't do anything

   you don't even have a chance to push anything into it
2. For each request you'll have a new `nicks`, it's not global